# Why some Java functions requires bytes array length when byte arrays object was already provided in the argument?

Tags: java, function, arguments

While writing Java code, I really wonder why some functions require byte arrays length as an argument when the first argument was byte arrays object. Why they don't get the length from the object provided?

For example:

```
// E.g.: 1. Bitmap
byte[] bytes = task.getResult();
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length);    

// E.g.: 2. Datagram
byte[] data = new byte[1024];
DatagramPacket request = new DatagramPacket(data, data.length);
```

If they want the length, why they don't use data.length?

Comment: Because the array might have a size of 1024, but data the data doesn't fill the whole array. You might initalize that array, pass it to ``InputStream.read`` and only 200 bytes contain actual data.

Comment: @f1sh, how can we know the length of actual data?

Comment: @LeapBun in this concrete example, ``read`` returns an ``int`` telling you how many bytes have been read. Other than that: take a look at how you fill the array and how you can get that information from that code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The byte array is a buffer to which data, the length of which is less than the length of the buffer,  is read. The length parameter defines the amount of bytes in the buffer that are relevant. You're not supposed to pass the length of the buffer in the parameter, that would be redundant. You're supposed to pass the number of bytes in the buffer that contain actual data.

The API documentation of DatagramPacket, for example, reveals this.

```
length - the number of bytes to read
```

Comment: And the reason the buffer size is allowed to be different from the number of bytes you actually want to read is performance: You can re-use the buffer (and pass it down the call hierarchy) instead of allocating a new array for every call. Same for `startOffset` that these functions also often have.

Comment: @Thilo It may be the case but for  `DatagramPacket` it doesn't matter as the read data are retrievable from `byte[] DatagramPacket.getData()`. And the classes filling the packet generally rely on that.

Comment: But usually, I see the number of bytes to read provided is equal to the buffer length. Why doesn't it have overload one?

Comment: @LeapBun This kind of methods are pretty much always meant to be called from a loop. A common casei is reading a stream (often a file). When reading a file the only time the you would need to pass a data length other than buffer.length would be the last iteration (when file ends). But what would you gain from an overloaded method? Would you make an if-else check inside the loop and call different method depending on data length? No, it's not worth it. For methods that are not usually called rom a loop (for example String constructor), there usually an overloaded version.

Comment: @LeapBun And even with files you can not assume that a read returns a full buffer even if there was enough data left. You might be reading from a network drive or some exotic device that does things you don't expect.

Comment: @Torben, it seems to be hard for me to understand this. I think the BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray() is more easy to understand. It's used to decode an immutable bitmap from the specified byte array. We already have byte array, why we still need the number of byte? Because the byte array already has information about the number of byte.

Comment: @LeapBun You have the information about the number of bytes in the array, but that might not be the same as the bytes that make up the compressed bitmap. In the end providing convenience methods is a decision made by the API designer. If the data-offset-length method is not available, one may force the developer to make copies of large arrays in memory. Comparing that to having to pass two parameters that are sometimes redundant is an easy tradeoff.

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is: most *read* methods (in Java, and any other language) that operate on **buffer arrays** have to tell you the exact number of bytes that were **actually** read.

Keep in mind: that array is an buffer. The *default* behavior is that buffer.length or **less** bytes can be read. So, knowing how *long* the buffer is doesn't help you. You have to know how many bytes were *actually* put into the buffer.

Comment: "colorful" and "code", you know how to make it happy :) And yours would be my first choice : it goes to the essential ;)

Answer (score 1):

Broadly a buffer is used as a temporary data in a data loading processing.
You fill the buffer until its size or less but never more than its capacity of course.
The `DatagramPacket` javadoc confirms that :

> The length argument must be less than or equal to buf.length.

And a thing that you don't have to forget : conceptually you use a buffer because  the data has to be progressively loaded or only a specific part of that.
In some cases you will read as much data as its maximal capacity but in some other cases you need to read only the X first bytes or the bytes from X to Y offset.
So the buffer class methods provide generally multiple way to read from the buffer.
Such as :

```
public DatagramPacket(byte buf[], int length);
public DatagramPacket(byte buf[], int offset, int length);
```

Now conceptually you are not wrong, sometimes you want to fill the whole buffer because you know that you will need to read exactly this size of data. 
The `java.net.DatagramSocket` confirms that :

```
public synchronized void receive(DatagramPacket p) throws IOException {
...
   tmp = new DatagramPacket(new byte[1024], 1024);
...
}
```

So an additional overloading such as :

```
public DatagramPacket(byte buf[]);
```

would make sense.

Comment: For network resources, it is often the case : you don't have really the "option". Thanks for this one :)

Comment: How about BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray()? We already known the bytes to decode, so we can know the length, why the function still requires other length?

Answer (score 0):

Because the data that you want to read can be **less than or equal to** `byte[] buf`'s length.

Below is the API documentation :

```
public DatagramPacket(byte[] buf,
              int length)

Constructs a DatagramPacket for receiving packets of length length.

The length argument must be less than or equal to buf.length.

Parameters:
    buf - buffer for holding the incoming datagram.
    length - the number of bytes to read.
```

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/DatagramPacket.html